# Communications Port (COM3) not working - Dell Vostro 3500 - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, device-manager

I seem to be unable to get the COM3 port to work on my Dell Vostro 3500 laptop. I am trying to work with the Arduino application, which requires COM3 to work.

The laptop has recently had a clean Windows 7 install, so I've suspected a driver issue so far. However, I have now installed several drivers from the Dell web site and none resolve the issue. Windows seems to think that the best driver is installed already - "Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date", so maybe drivers are not the problem.

All USB ports are enabled in BIOS, nothing so far as I can see is disabled.

What can I do to resolve this issue? Device manager just shows a warning triangle. Is there a specific driver I'm missing?

Comment: Why COM3 specifically?  It would more likely be COM1, no?

Comment: When I from having no COM Ports visible in Device Manager, then go > Add Legacy Hardware > Communications Port, COM3 is the first that is added. Also, the Arduino IDE that I am using defaults to COM3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be resolved by looking at this arduino thread that details installation issues.

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload